# Checkbox and BackgroundImage size issue

Tags: vb.net, image, checkbox, background

I want to do a really simple thing, but it doesn't appear to be as simple as I thought it would be. I had a `Checkbox` with `Appearance.Button` and two `BackgroundImage`s depending on the current state. I chose `Appearance.Button` to avoid the "box" itself. But I want to get rid of the border of the `Checkbox` because my images already got borders and that's why I switched back to `Appearance.Normal`.

The problem is I don't know how to (if possible) hide the box.

With Android for instance I can do this :

```
myCheckbox.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent); //Hide the "box"
myCheckbox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myImages); //Display my images
```

Is there any way to do this in .net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found a way :

```
myCheckbox.Appearance = Appearance.Button
myCheckbox.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
myCheckbox.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
```

I left `Appearance.Button` but I needed to change `Flat` properties.

I leave the thread in case someone has the same problem, it still could help one day. Feel free to delete it if you think it won't.